# ItextSharp PDF Conversion

Tags: itext

I have  created table in a html editor with output

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><a href="http://www.google.com">sdfsdf</a><br></td>
            <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br></td>
            <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And used Itextsharp html to PDF conversion as follows

```
private List<IElement> GetXHtmlElementList(string html)
    {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html) && html.Contains("<img"))
       {
          html = html.Replace("<img", "<br/><img");
       }
        List<IElement> list = new List<IElement>();
        Dictionary<string, object> interfaceProps = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            {"img_provider", new CustomItextImageProvider()}
        };
        if (html != null)
        {
            var encodedHTML = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
            if(encodedHTML != null)
                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedHTML)))
                {
                    list = ParseToList(sr, null, interfaceProps);
                }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But am getting following error
in ParseToList

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'."}

I may need to think to switch other options if this won't work, I have not found any solution so far.

Comment: That looks like iTextSharp code, but not quite. What is this `ParseToList()` you are using? Also, are you sure you're using the most recent version of iText? The `simpleparser` package has been deprecated a long time ago, hasn't it?

Comment: Yeah using the latest XMLWorkerHelper gives good result.But now no idea how we could pass providers to  XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, CSS);

Comment: What is the replacement for   Dictionary<string, object> interfaceProps = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            {"img_provider", new CustomItextImageProvider()}
        }; in XMLWorkerHrlper

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. It seems that you are doing paid work for a customer, but you responded with surprise when Joris offered to use iText 7 + pdfHTML. You wrote: *It seems paid* as if that surprised you. Please be aware that using older versions of iText also require a paid license. If your customer wants to use iTextSharp, there is a high chance that he will have to buy a commercial license. Please consult with your customer and discuss commercial license prices before you decide *not* to work with the latest iText(Sharp) version.

Comment: Yeah i understood from your point...I will get client to buy licence as i was using old version and i was unaware of the same sorry.Now i read and understood and won't be any issue to buy licence.But if you have some insights on how to fix the above problem i will be more confident

Comment: Well, I have formatted your HTML code, and I see `<tbody>` (which isn't supported by `HTMLWorker`) and I see a `<br>` without a closing tag (which isn't supported by XML Worker). The error you get (*Unable to cast...*) tells me that you have a `<p>` or `<div>` tag where a `<td>` tag is expected. I can't tell you more without seeing more of your HTML (that is: the final HTML that is produced by your HTML editor).

Comment: So whom i contact for itextsharp licence and who maintain this and same with Itext and what you prefer and why? sorry for lot of questions i got but confused

Comment: iText is a registered trademark of iText Group NV (ISG). iText Group NV has three subsidiaries in three different continents. If you live in the Americas, you can contact iText Software Corp. (ISC); if you live in the EMEA region, you can contact iText Software BVBA (ISB); if you live in Asia/Pacific, you can contact iText Software Asia Ptr. Ltd. (ISA). The contact info can be found here: https://itextpdf.com/contact The library is maintained by a team of developers working for one of the forementioned companies (ISG, ISA, ISB, or ISC). Using the latest version of the software is preferred.

Comment: So itextsharp is not using any more?

Comment: The library itself still exists, but since iText 7, the name has changed to iText for .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're used to working with iText, consider using pdfHTML. It's an iText7 add-on that provides conversion from HTML to PDF in a way that is far superior than XMLWorker.

Small code sample:

```
    // IO
    String htmlSource = "<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>";
    File pdfDest = getOutputFile();

    // pdfHTML specific code
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
        new FileInputStream(htmlSource), 
        new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), 
        converterProperties);
```

Learn more at https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

Comment: It seems paid and customer want to do in itextsharp Thanks

Comment: pdfHTML will be open-sourced. For now, you can of course use a free-trial key. (If you are planning on using this in a commercial context however, you are required to pay a licensing fee.)

Comment: So what is the difference between itextsharp and and itext who own each project and for each licence who should i contact?